# С чем употреблять?

Tags: употребление-слов

Допустимо ли употреблять слово "пурга" со словом "идти"? Может ли пурга идти? Не в том смысле, чтобы приближаться или наступать.

Answer (score 2):

Глаголы с пургой бывают самые разнообразные.
Поднялась (Лесков), зачиналась (Тургенев), стонет, воет и крутит (Дорошевич), проносится над спящим городом (Вал.Курицын), вскипела (А.Белый), разразилась, метет, дует, задувает (...), кружит (Федин), бушевала (Бианки)...

> В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. (1913-1932)
> ― Вьюга. **Пурга идет** {надвигается}, ― отрывисто сказал он. ― Ничего, крепись, джигит. ...
>
> Лишь слышно было, как **ревела пурга**, как вырывала она с корнями деревья и с гулом валила наземь. ...
>
> Действительно, по вчерашним грязным улицам с позеленевшей на лужайке травкой **дурила вовсю свирепая пурга**, наметая сугробы снега. ...
>
> **Пурга угомонилась**, ветер стих, народ помаленьку разбредался.

Comment: Здесь  "идёт"  именно  в  значении  надвигается,  приближается  как  враг.  И  с  тем  же  отношением  к  пурге  как  к  врагу.  Здесь  метафора.  Про  уже  пришедшую  пургу  будут  рассказывать  с  помощью  других  слов.  Как  в  вашем  примере.

Answer (score 1):

Идет обычно дождь, снег идет. Пурга, наверное, метет.

Comment: Возможно речь идет о каком-то конкретном предложении и отношении к нему (например, учителя)  Если так, дайте предложение целиком (или даже в контексте), возможно оно окажется красивым или хотя бы приемлемым.

Answer (score 1):

Ребенком я, не зная страху,
Хоть вечер был и **шла метель**,
Блуждал в лесу, и встретил пряху,
И полюбил ее кудель.
                /Валерий Брюсов/

Comment: Возможно  так  лучше  в  строчку  легло.  Так  сказать,  частный  случай.

Comment: На таком языке тогда разговаривали.

Comment: Идет пурга слепыми облаками
В безлюдные и людные места...
Заносит снег лукавые капканы;
Рука ловца ласкает мех песца.

Comment: Нет, тут опять про её ПЕРЕМЕЩЕНИЕ, а не про то, ЧТО ОНА ДЕЛАЕТ, когда есть.

Answer (score 1):

Пурга идти не может, так как этот глагол не уместен хотя бы уже по характеру самого происходящего процесса. Соглашусь со [@Злата](/users/2146/%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0), дождь или снег могут ИДТИ. А вот про ураган, смерч и иные динамичные атмосферные явления (в том числе, пургу) так не скажешь.

Comment: Полностью  согласен.